# The language change implemented in the Android app does not work

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application where I have implemented the code to be able to change the language within the application through a popup where a button appears per language. Testing it from the Android Studio emulators works fine for me, but later when I test the application downloaded from the Play Store, the language change does not work.

This is what I have in the code:

In the application of the AndroidManifest.xml I have set **android:supportsRtl = "true"**

In each activity of the AndroidManifest.xml I have set **android:configChanges = "... | locale"**

Clicking on a language button in the popup window where the languages ​​are displayed does the following:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("currentLocale", "es");
editor.apply();
Intent intent = new Intent(LanguagePopup.this, InitActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

For each activity I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = newBase.getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentLocale = sharedPreferences.getString("currentLocale", "en");
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, currentLocale));
}
```

I also have the class:

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {
    public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }
    
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale sysLocale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
        } else {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
        if (!"".equals(language) && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return new MyContextWrapper(context);
    }

    public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config){
        return config.locale;
    }
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config){
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }
    
    public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale){
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

I have created the values/strings.xml, values-en/strings.xml and values-en/strings.xml

Can you help me with this?

Thanks.